# Can we write a oracle query using order by of a column without group by of that column

Tags: mysql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by, concatenation

I have written the below query. Its not giving any output

```
select mfg_name, wm_concat(cal_wid||','||mkt_share) concated_mkt_share from shares group by mfg_name order by cal_wid
```

When I used the below code it worked fine when I included `cal_wid` in `group by`

```
select mfg_name, wm_concat(cal_wid||','||mkt_share) concated_mkt_share from shares group by mfg_name, **cal_wid** order by cal_wid
```

I am using jquery to append these values to some application. The output of the second query does not support my application. `I am trying to use the first query but with order by of cal_wid. So can I use the cal_wid without using it in group_by`

Comment: It is giving output - its reporting an error. That you can't see the error implies a defect in your code elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
select mfg_name, wm_concat(cal_wid || ',' || mkt_share) as concated_mkt_share
from shares
group by mfg_name
order by cal_wid;
```

You cannot order by `cal_wid` because there is more than one `cal_wid` for each row in the result set.  Oracle does not know which value you want for ordering.

You can order by an aggregation function, such as `min()` or `max()` or `sum()`:

```
order by min(cal_id)
```

Comment: No change. I am getting the same result

Answer (score 1):

When selecting just fields from a table or tables, any field, whether you have it in the select list or not, can be used for sorting.

However, when you group the result set, you no longer have the other fields available like that. Now you are not just working with rows but with groups of rows and any field(s) inside each group can only be passed out of the group as the result of aggregation.

That means sorting can only be performed on the grouping fields or the aggregation results. Your query has one grouping field and one aggregate result. So only four sorting options are available:

```
select  mfg_name, wm_concat(cal_wid||','||mkt_share) concated_mkt_share
from    shares
group by mfg_name
order by mfg_name;
```

or

```
order by wm_concat(cal_wid||','||mkt_share);
```

or

```
order by mfg_name, wm_concat(cal_wid||','||mkt_share);
```

or

```
order by wm_concat(cal_wid||','||mkt_share), mfg_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove 'and' from your query,

```
select mfg_name, wm_concat(cal_wid||','||mkt_share) concated_mkt_share from shares group by mfg_name order by cal_wid
```

this gives output ,

```
select crm_campaign_id, concat(end||','|title) from events 
group by crm_campaign_id  order by end
```

Comment: it is the mistake while typing here. That is not the mistake actually